# composition of two functions problem

Tags: calculus

Let $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  and for $n=0$ we define $\mathbb{R}^{0}$  to be just a point.  Consider two functions

$$i:\mathbb{R}^{0}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$$ ''that sends $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ to the origin''(do they mean the origin of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ i.e the point $(0,...,0,..,0)$?) ''and consider

$$p:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{0}$$

then $p\circ i=id$'' (meaning identity on $\mathbb{R}^{0}$?), ''also  $i\circ p$ a projection of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ onto the origin (the origin of $\mathbb{R}^{0}$?)

Why isn't $i\circ p$  an identity as well? Please explain the above functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we associate $\Bbb R^0$ with zero.

$p\circ i$ is a function $\Bbb R^0\to\Bbb R^0$, $0\to 0$, hence it's an identity.

$i\circ p$ is a projection, because $(i\circ p)\circ (i\circ p)= i\circ p  $ (check it). It is not an identity, because if we take $x\ne 0$, $x\in \Bbb R^n$, then $i\circ p(x)=0\ne x$.

Comment: Superb explanation! Thank you TZakrevskiy:)